# How To Use Epoch Time With Highcharts Series Data?

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying use epoch time dates in my series data. The array looks like this:

```
data:[ [1324857600,205.4],[1324771200,208.7],[1324684800,205.4]. . .]
```

The points display fine, but the date labels on the x-axis and tooltip are all set to 16 Jan 1970 (the beginning of epoch time!).

If I do a bunch of string-fu I can produce an array that looks like this:

```
 data:[ [Date.UTC(2011, 11, 26),247.7],[Date.UTC(2011, 11, 25),245.5] . . .]
```

When I do it this way the date labels on the x-axis are correct.

I've tried using the dateTimeLabelFormat option and it formats the date correctly - it's just that when I try to use millisecond values all I get is 16 Jan 70.

Any ideas? I'd rather work with milliseconds than jump through all the hoops to produce "Date.UTC(2011, 11, 26)."

Thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Found the answer on the Highsoft forum.

I need to multiply the epoch time values by 1000 to get the proper millisecond values for Highcharts.

Works great!

Comment: link to the referenced forum thread:   [link](http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=14855)

Comment: This works amazingly well! I have a chart which is a burn-down chart. With this solution it now automatically adjusts to work for small (like hours) and large timeframes (like days)