# Highstocks epoch time mismatch with time zone

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts

I am trying to populate a graph using highstocks library. I am giving epoch time as input for x axis. I am able to generate the graph successfully but the problem is that the epoch time converted by highstock is mismatching with my time zone. For example

My input epoch time is : 1347497100000

Present result after convertion is: Thu, 13 Sep 2012 00:45:00 GMT

Expected result is : Wed Sep 12 2012 17:45:00 GMT-0700

This time zone mis match is the wrong value which is being displayed right now.

I tried setting this property also, but no luck:

```
global: {
    useUTC: false
},
```

I am in pacific time zone. When I tried doing :

```
console.log(new Date)
```

from the same script, it returns me the time in pacific time.

Can you please advice how to fix the mismatch of this time zone ?

Comment: Here is the jsfidle link: http://jsfiddle.net/SLB4P/1/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It may be a good idea to read the [global.useUTC](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#global.useUTC) api reference again

> Global options that don't apply to each chart. These options,
>   like the lang options, must be set using the Highcharts.setOptions
>   method.

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
        useUTC: false
    }
});
```

What that means is the global property is not really applicable to any chart in particular and `Highcharts` would blindly ignore the option even if you set it in an individual chart like

```
var chart=new Highcharts.StockChart({
{
  ...
    global: {
        useUTC: false
    }
  ...
});
```

In short set the global option explicitly using the `Highcharts.setOptions` method before you create any chart object
[Local/Client Time Zone | Highchart & Highstock @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/RvRSB/)

Comment: Ah, Global vs. Local-Chart Options. Unexpected. Sincere thanks. This may well be beneficial in upcoming implementation. +1.

Answer (score 0):

Conversion problems are an extremely common occurrence whenever dealing with date and time.

[This link here shows the solution, to multiply by 1000, to get correct version.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648861/how-to-use-epoch-time-with-highcharts-series-data)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for replying but my problem is not about sec vs millisecond, its picking the wrong timezone. To verify my epoch value, I tried online with 2 different epoch converters and I got 2 diff values. One gives for GMT timezone and other gives for Pacific time zone. I need for pacific timezone but I am getting gmt time zone when plotting with highcharts / highstocks.  I also tried multiplying my value with 1000 but the conversion gives me an year 6240. Any advice ? here is jsfidle link also: http://jsfiddle.net/SLB4P/1/

Comment: Awesome clarification. Yes. Taking a look. Ah, so I see. +1. All the best.