# Highcharts thinks all dates are 1970-01-01, despite them being valid epoch times

Tags: highcharts, epoch

I'm working with this simple chart:

https://jsfiddle.net/w7uyghqn/2/

My dates are in the format: `Date(1447793679000)`, which translates correctly to `Thu Aug 11 2016 10:26:59 GMT-0400 (EDT)`.

```
var seriesOptions = [
    {
        "data":[
            [Date(1447793679000), 7.8494623656],
            [Date(1450913358000), 5.4140127389],
            [Date(1460475392000), 6.015037594],
            [Date(1460648544000), 3.75],
            [Date(1460753244000), 2.1015761821],
            [Date(1460985174000), 3.0141843972],
            [Date(1460988174000), 5.2264808362],
            [Date(1461874589000), 1.5100671141]
        ],
        "name":"Product 1"
    },
    {
        "data":[
            [Date(1450729647000), 2.9850746269],
            [Date(1452184898000), 4.1666666667],
            [Date(1454616863000), 4.1749502982],
            [Date(1455206741000), 2.6717557252],
            [Date(1458062356000), 2.4],
            [Date(1459868909000), 3.8461538462],
            [Date(1459882015000), 3.3955857385],
            [Date(1459968893000), 4.1832669323],
            [Date(1460574864000), 4.973357016],
            [Date(1460665314000), 5.2032520325]
        ],
        "name":"Product 2"
    }
]
```

However, as you can see on the x-axis, this is all Jan 1st 1970. Can anyone spot what's wrong?

I've tried so many different formats and I'm totally tearing my hair out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Use Epoch Time With Highcharts Series Data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648861/how-to-use-epoch-time-with-highcharts-series-data)

Comment: remove the "Date()" portion of your timestamps. This: **[Date(1450729647000), 2.9850746269]** should be: **[1450729647000, 2.9850746269]** Your stamps, as they are, are being interpreted as some number of seconds, less than a day, which results in a date of the first day of Epoch time - January 1, 1970

Comment: [Docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.type): _In a datetime axis, the numbers are given in milliseconds_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As jlbriggs said in the comments, you can simply remove the `Date()` function and use the actual number which will automatically be interpreted by HighCharts as the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970 because you told it that the `xAxis.type` is `datetime`.

I modified your JSFiddle and fixed the problem so you can see it:  [**Working JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/6ej4vyw6/)

```
var seriesOptions = [
    {
        "data":[
            [1447793679000, 7.8494623656],
            [1450913358000, 5.4140127389],
            [1460475392000, 6.015037594],
            [1460648544000, 3.75],
            [1460753244000, 2.1015761821],
            [1460985174000, 3.0141843972],
            [1460988174000, 5.2264808362],
            [1461874589000, 1.5100671141]
        ],
        "name":"Product 1"
    },{
        "data":[
            [1450729647000, 2.9850746269],
            [1452184898000, 4.1666666667],
            [1454616863000, 4.1749502982],
            [1455206741000, 2.6717557252],
            [1458062356000, 2.4],
            [1459868909000, 3.8461538462],
            [1459882015000, 3.3955857385],
            [1459968893000, 4.1832669323],
            [1460574864000, 4.973357016],
            [1460665314000, 5.2032520325]
        ],
        "name":"Product 2"
    }
]
```