# Is highcharts.js capable of formatting integer timestamps into dates?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am getting series of numbers from server in pairs of date and value. Dates are unix timestamps.

Should I map these timestamps on my own or Highcharts.js can do it for me somehow?

**Clarification:**
This is not a question about how to show Unix Epoch timestamp with Highcharts. This is a question about possibilities of Highcharts.js to consume **correct** data in timestamp format and automatically translate it to `Date`, without any work on my side.

Comment: Highcharts uses time in milliseconds (ref: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data.x) , so if you do `unixTimestamp * 1000` highchart will format it as a date for you (as long as you set axis type to datetime (ref: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.type))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Use Epoch Time With Highcharts Series Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648861/how-to-use-epoch-time-with-highcharts-series-data)

Comment: @ewolden clarified question. It's not duplicate.

Comment: I don't agree on that point, especially given that the other question states **Any ideas? I'd rather work with milliseconds than jump through all the hoops to produce "Date.UTC(2011, 11, 26)."**.

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts is a library that servers only to visualize data - not to process it. You have to provide it with the format of timestamp specified in the **API** (@ewolden provided a link to it in his comment under your question).

Answer (score 0):

In Highcharts, you can format the Unix Timestamp this way :

```
xAxis: {        
        type: 'datetime',
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                return Highcharts.dateFormat('%a %d %b %H:%M:%S', this.value);
            }
        }
}
```

Of course, this parameter : `'%a %d %b %H:%M:%S'` lets choose what part of the datetime you want to display in the axis.