# Highcharts data showing wrong

Tags: graph, highcharts, tooltip

I am trying to build a chart for tracking my project status. I have given input as timestamp(in 2018) but it is showing wrong year(which is from 1969).
The code is as follows

```
<script>
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Project Status'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['BOT POC', 'Analytics POC', 'CRM POC']
    },
    yAxis: {
         type: 'datetime',
    labels: {
        rotation: -65,
        style: {
            fontSize: '9px',
            fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
        }
    },
    crosshair: true,
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
      week:"Week from %A, %b %e, %Y",         
  }
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                this.x +': '+ this.y;
        }
    },
    legend: {
        reversed: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking: 'normal'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Scoping In Progress',
        data: [1528635194, 1528203194, 1527252794]
    }, {
        name: 'Scoping Complete',
        data: [1528807994, 1528375994, 1527511994]
    },  {
        name: 'Development in Progress',
        data: [1528894394, 1528462394, 1527943994]
    }]
});
</script>
```

The result is as follows
[image: Output chart]

How can the date brought to current date/year?

Comment: You have given time in seconds since 1970. Highcharts expects milliseconds since 1970.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Use Epoch Time With Highcharts Series Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648861/how-to-use-epoch-time-with-highcharts-series-data)

Comment: @ewolden. If I multiply the data by 1000, the start date remains in 1970 and end date is in 2018

Comment: It does remain in 1970 because you are using a bar chart. A bar chart gives bars from `x: 0` to `x: value`. For your purpose, you probably want to use an xrange graph.